# Where are the sound level settings for mplayer saved?

Tags: configuration, mplayer

This is a followup to [Somehow managed to mute mplayer and can't figure out how to restore sound](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131827/4671).

I've noticed that the sound level settings in mplayer are saved on exit. However, I can't figure out where they are saved. There are config files in the `.mplayer` directory, but none of them are being written to.

This is on Debian wheezy with mplayer version `2:1.0~rc4.dfsg1+svn3454`.

Comment: I don't think mplayer saves the settings, but rather your driver. Please take a look at this link : http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2012-February/084207.html

Comment: @NNzz Thanks for the comment, but I don't follow. I have no idea what the XVideo driver is. And how would the settings be saved in a driver? What driver?

Comment: Pulse Audio is saving the settings, I thought I showed that in the A to the [other Q](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131827/4671).

Comment: For the record, I don't think this question is a duplicate of my earlier (referenced) question. It was intended as a followup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PulseAudio stores stream state for each app independently. This lets you (for example) set your music player to a lower volume than your instant message alert tone, so you hear the IM alert over the music.

If you have PulseAudio's [`module-stream-restore`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index28h3) loaded—and the default config loads it—, then these settings will be saved when you exit the program and loaded back when you start it again.

The settings are saved in `~/.pulse/…stream-volumes.tdb`.

The easiest way to change them is by starting mplayer again, and then using one of the many PulseAudio UIs, e.g., command-line `pactl`, GUI `pavucontrol`, etc. to change it. If mplayer is using the PulseAudio mixer (likely), then you can also try <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, and <kbd>0</kbd> (mplayer's default mute and volume keys).

Comment: I thought I kinda showed/hinted to this in my A to the other Q?

Comment: @slm yep. Feel free to VtC as a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

They would be saved in your `alsa` configuration (or the sound architecture you're using, e.g. `pulseaudio`; `alsa` is default in debian).

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Global_view_of_ALSA_config_file_framework.2C_executive_summary

They might be in `/etc/asound.state`, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings.

Comment: Can you say which file they would be saved in, and why vlc and xine are unaffected?