# Get a list of applications that are playing sound

Tags: bash, command-line, audio

I want to get a list of applications that are currently playing sound (using the sound card).

I tried to search on a lot of places but did not succeed. Any method is fine (bash, Java, etc.). I want to have a distribution-independent solution but specific solutions for one distribution (e.g. Ubuntu) is also appreciated.

The data of the sound is not important as of now. I just want the fact that an application is playing sound. Also the program can have root permission if necessary.

Comment: You have not given enough information for the question to be answered. There are multiple sound servers (e.g., OSS, alsa, jack, pulse), and getting information on audio streams will be different for each one. Which are you interested in?

Comment: @HalosGhost I want to write a generic program that can run on most computers. Is there a standard API from Linux OS that I can use?

Comment: Again, not really. You can write/run a generic program that will run on most computers, but having it function for all the various sound servers will be difficult.

Comment: @HalosGhost isn't it possible to get the names of all processes sending data to the sound device?

Comment: @terdon, possibly, but I'm not even sure that all linux sound servers even work in that way.

Comment: Moderately related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131827/somehow-managed-to-mute-mplayer-and-cant-figure-out-how-to-restore-sound

Comment: @terdon Could you explain more on how to list all processes sending data to sound device?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't even know if it's possible. I would have posted an answer if I did. It might not be possible. I think it's probably the sound server that interacts with the sound device so you will always need to query the server and not the device. I really don't know though.

Comment: If you run this command: `pactl list clients` you can see all the clients that are using the sound server, assuming you're using Pulse Audio.

Comment: @slm that assumes that the sound server is PulseAudio (reasonable, but not always correct). as HalosGhost mentions, it could be OSS, JACK, or even raw ALSA.

Comment: @strugee - thanks, forgot to say that, updated that comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/323004/290645) for Ubuntu, works for pulse.. so will most likely work for most OS using `pulse`

`pacmd list-sink-inputs`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1020281/2089697) is one for `alsa`

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/fd/*
do
    var="$(readlink $i)"
    if test x"$var" != x"${var#/dev/snd/pcm}"
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: If `pacmd` and `pactl` are too overwhelming, there's also [`ponymix`](https://github.com/falconindy/ponymix) which seeks to be a little more manageable.

Comment: This (`pacmd`) didn't work for me on my Fedora 20 system.