# Identify and remove noisy software

Tags: audio, cpu, services, daemon, cpu-usage

When I open up my session, my laptop speakers start whining. This does not happen when I use the guest user session.

The noise stops when there is CPU activity (for eg. moving mouse, starting program, etc.), especially when a full CPU core is in use (`cat /dev/zero > /dev/null`).

The noise used to be strong only when I'd plug an external soundcard, but now it just happens whenever my session is open, even if I'm using another session. 
 Weirdly, when I do not use the desktop, but I'm logged only through a tty, the noise is a lot weaker. -- Edit, apparently it happens in two situations (still only while I'm logged in):

1. The soundcard is plugged in and in use.
2. Firefox is running (weaker noise, not all the time, rarer after restarting firefox several times).

I'd like to identify what software makes my laptop produce this noise when idle, then stop it or remove it.

---

My laptop is an Acer Swift (NC-SF314-51-74FW).

```
$ uname -mr
4.15.0-23-generic x86_64

$ lsb_release -cds
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
bionic

$ yes | alsa-info | grep -o 'http.*'
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=fc032e6cb8cdc2317ea76f852c1e2a954c7dd315

$ ls /etc/rc5.d/S* | pastebin # services
https://pastebin.com/CCT5Ju6U

$ dpkg -l | pastebin
https://pastebin.com/ZsDm5w7e
```

Comment: Pastebins will expire on 2018-07-23.

Comment: It might just be a really bad SNR, and the guest login is not enabaling sound at all. Try extra grounding when using your account, and playing some sounds on the guest account.

Comment: If I had to guess, your volume is too high/amplified/loud.´At least this, or a combination of factors. What happens with the volume at 50%-70%?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the way to here in terms of figuring out what's using the soundcard using either `fuser` or `lsof` to determine which processes are using it. Searching I found this SU Q&A titled: [How can I find out what programs are using sound in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/47146/how-can-i-find-out-what-programs-are-using-sound-in-linux).

The examples from one of the answers there:

*lsof*

```
$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi 1142 burhan  mem    CHR  116,3          7885 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   21u   CHR  116,5      0t0 7887 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   28u   CHR  116,5      0t0 7887 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   36r   CHR 116,33      0t0 6351 /dev/snd/timer
pulseaudi 1142 burhan   37u   CHR  116,3      0t0 7885 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
```

*fuser*

```
$ fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  burhan     1142 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   burhan     1142 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/timer:      burhan     1142 f.... pulseaudio
```

If you find you're running into pulse audio, you can use `pavucontrol` to further debug/follow it through that GUI. Refer to one of my other answers which shows this GUI in this UL Q&A titled: [Somehow managed to mute mplayer and can't figure out how to restore sound](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131827/somehow-managed-to-mute-mplayer-and-cant-figure-out-how-to-restore-sound/131832#131832).

Answer (score 0):

And in addition to the other answer of how to check for ALSA/Pulseaudio clients:

I suspect that the reason is not a particular client, but bad settings on the various amplifiers in your sound codec (including loopbacks). To debug these, the best way is to use `amixer -c 42 contents` (where `42` is the number of your card), and look at *all* of them to see if there's anything suspicious.

Once you have an idea which volume settings are available, you can also use `alsamixer` for live changes (don't forget to scroll left/right). Also pay attention to what is muted, or not.